# Allow for easier tag tapping

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Tapping a tag is extremely hard (for me, at least), how about:

- making them bigger? or
- enlarge the tap area? or
- maybe allow to long-tap to display and select from a floating list of tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made the tap area bigger in the next release.  15pt above and 15pt below, so a single row of tags has a respectable tap height of 43pt (close to Apple's preferred 44pt) and with two rows the tap height is 28pt.  Not as amazing but tappable.

I've been able to tap [git](/questions/tagged/git) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) reliably so I feel good about this.

You'll see it in the next build.

Comment: If you can tap [tag:c], you are either a certified ninja, or have the fingers of a small child.

Comment: I'm having trouble tapping [tag:c] on the desktop.